# I want to retrieve the web's properties, but why I can not find .Load

Tags: c#, sharepoint, csom

I want to retrieve the web's properties, but why I can not find .Load?

```
ClientContext con = new ClientContext("https://example.com");
Web web = con.Web;
con.Load(web);
```

[image]

Comment: please provide code as texts in code block rather than image..

Comment: Follow the documentation, either the Load method is wrong or its the wrong library. Also see what options you have in the intellisense context menu.

Answer (score 0):

Add reference **Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll** in your console application.